# Запрос в Google на python

Tags: python

Добрый день, нужно сделать запрос в Гугл на питоне и вытащить первые 10 страниц, их адреса к примеру. Установил python 3.3. Поискал примеры, библиотека urllib2 приводилась, как стандартная, я так понял что в версии 3.3 её нет... В общем как мне сделать то, что я хочу, буду благодарен за небольшой пример или ссылку на пример... спасибо.

Comment: ага, нашел пример в python...\scripts\google.py
теперь запуская его, открывается браузер с ключ словом, которое я ввел, и как теперь мне взять адреса первых 10 стр...

Answer (score 2):

Делаем запрос с помощью

```
data = urllib2.urlopen(query)
```

, где query - это урл с подставленной строкой поиска.
Читаем оттуда данные и формируем документ

```
import lxml.html as lhtml
document = lhtml.document_fromstring(data.read())
```

Ну и дальше раскапывать этот документ с помощью той же lxml, например.

Про urlopen [тут](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html), про lxml.html - [здесь](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html)
Также стоит посмотреть в сторону модуля [Grab](http://docs.grablib.org/), хотя 99% его функционала в этой задаче использовано не будет :)

Comment: эм, насколько я знаю такого рода решения никак не спасут автора т.к. в ответе будет страница с пустыми результатами (которые потом заполнятся аяксом), не?

Answer (score 0):

Ekkertan все верно написал. Только учти, что гугл может принять тебя за робота и начать тебе возвращать вместо страницы выдачи - страницу с капчей. Так что неплохо бы еще косить под реальный браузер: принимать cookies, заполнить поле user agent, referer, рандомный sleep между запросами, если в цикле это делаешь.

Comment: Ну да, гугл может подумать плохое :)
Впрочем, проблему кук и заголовков запроса тот же grub вполне решает